# Какой селектор использовать для поиска элемента по data-атрибуту?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Есть скрипт который работает по клику на IMG.
Как правильно поставить условие, что если IMG имеет атрибут `data-text="test"`, то скрипт не применять?

P.S Контент лежит в одном блоке, переверстывать или как то отбирать по другому не вариант ( `$('img.Class')` ) Добавлять класс к нужной IMG тоже не вариант: страниц очень много, и перебирать руками это ад, контент динамический.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('img:not([data-text="test"])').click(function() {
  console.log("aloha");
});
```

```css
img {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img data-text="test"/>
<img data-text="test"/>
<img>
```

Answer (score 1):

Используйте селектор `img[data-text="test"]`. Если искомое слово `"test"` является одним из других слов внутри атрибута `data-text`, то воспользуйтесь оператором `~=`, то есть так: `img[data-text~="test"]`.

То есть приведенный мной первый селектор не сработает в случае если элемент имеет вид `<img data-text="something and test and something else">`, а вот второй сработает.